# incompatible types int need string

Tags: java, int, incompatibletypeerror

I need it to be an int to return but it keeps saying

```
----jGRASP exec: javac -g CSCD210Lab8Functions.java

CSCD210Lab8Functions.java:118: incompatible types
found   : int
required: java.lang.String
      return finalExam;





 public static String readFinalScore(Scanner kb)
   {int finalExam;
      do{
         kb.nextLine();
         System.out.print("Enter the score of the final-->");
         finalExam = kb.nextInt();
         kb.nextLine();
         if (finalExam<0)
         {System.out.print("Invalid answer please try again " );}
      }while(finalExam<0);
      return finalExam;
```

i casted it as an int and then kb.nextInt not sure why it's freaking out

Comment: reuturn type is `String` and `finalExam` is int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String readFinalScore(Scanner kb) // return type String
{int finalExam; // finalExam is int
...
return finalExam;   // returning int value when it expects String
```

return type is `String` and `finalExam` is int.

Change to

```
public static int readFinalScore(Scanner kb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning an `int` when it wants a `String`

Change:

```
public static String readFinalScore(Scanner kb)
```

Into:

```
public static int readFinalScore(Scanner kb)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to declared your method to return `String`, java won't automatically convert an `int` to a `String`.

Change your `return` statement to:

```
return String.valueOf(finalExam);
```

Or you can "cheat" too:

```
return finalExam + "";
```

---

However, if you really want to return an `int`, then declare your method like this:

```
public static int readFinalScore(Scanner kb)
```

Your current method code will then work.

Comment: He is expecting int as return value... read the question correctly.

Comment: @Hariharan maybe. Hard to tell. Anyway answered for both possibilities now

Answer (score 0):

Your return declaration is incorrect. you should change to `int` instead of `String`.

```
public static int readFinalScore(Scanner kb)

   return finalExam ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement do not match..

So you can use `Integer.toString(finalExam)` to return String type

Hope it helps..